# Failed to build Android: soong bootstrap failed with exit status 1

Tags: android, operating-system, android-source

At the moment, I am playing around with Android, figuring out how to build my own custom Android ROM, and everything seems to be going well. All until I start to compile Android.

When I enter `make -j2 aapt` into the terminal, after a little bit of time, stops with an error. This is the entire make process.

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=VanillaIceCream
PLATFORM_VERSION=VanillaIceCream
PRODUCT_INCLUDE_TAGS=com.android.mainline
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.2.0-31-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.3-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
BUILD_ID=AOSP.MAIN
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
[ 33% 1/3] converting Android.bp files to BUILD files at out/soong/bp2build
FAILED: out/soong/bp2build_files_marker
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out
 "out"     --soong_variables out/soong/soong.aosp_arm.variables --bp2build_marker out/soong/bp2build_files_marker --globListDir bp2build_files --globFile out/soong/globs-bp2build_files.ninja -t -l out/.mo
dule_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.aosp_arm.bp2build_files Android.bp
error: external/llvm/Android.bp:66:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_defaults"
error: frameworks/compile/mclinker/tools/mcld/Android.bp:29:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_tblgen"
error: external/llvm/Android.bp:195:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_tblgen"
error: external/llvm/Android.bp:201:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_tblgen"
error: external/llvm/Android.bp:207:1: unrecognized module type "force_build_llvm_components_defaults"
error: external/clang/Android.bp:119:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_tblgen"
error: frameworks/compile/slang/Android.bp:163:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_tblgen"
fatal errors encountered
14:50:38 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (4 seconds) ####
```

For more context, I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a 64 bit platform and have 32GB of RAM (which I am upgrading to 64 GB soon). Also, I'm building Android off of the main branch in AOSP.

For the record, I already tried a lot of suggestions I found on the internet, which mostly stated "get more RAM" or "use `make -j2 aapt`". None of these actually worked.